# NetWkstaGetInfo ACCESS_VIOLATION under WIN64

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm have code, which works fine during many years under WIN32. But yesterday, after compiling under WIN64 I'm got strange ACCESS_VIOLATION error when trying get wki100_langroup field. Where wrong this code? (Computer not in domain and in Delphi 11 debug window I can see, that this field is empty)

```
const
  NERR_SUCCESS = 0;

type
  WKSTA_INFO_100 = record
    wki100_platform_id: DWORD;
    wki100_computername: LPWSTR;
    wki100_langroup: LPWSTR;
    wki100_ver_major: DWORD;
    wki100_ver_minor: DWORD;
  end;
  LPWKSTA_INFO_100 = ^WKSTA_INFO_100;

function NetWkstaGetInfo(ServerName: LPWSTR; Level: DWORD; var BufPtr: Pointer): DWORD; stdcall;
  external 'netapi32.dll' Name 'NetWkstaGetInfo';

function GetDomain: string;
var
  PBuf: Pointer;
  Res: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  Res := NetWkstaGetInfo(nil, 100, PBuf);
  if (Res = NERR_Success) then begin
    Result := LPWKSTA_INFO_100(PBuf)^.wki100_langroup; // ACCESS_VIOLATION here
    if Assigned(PBuf) then
      NetApiBufferFree(PBuf);
  end;
end;
```

**Update:**
After changing Pointer to PByte I have the same exception

```
function NetWkstaGetInfo(ServerName: LPWSTR; Level: DWORD; BufPtr: PByte): DWORD; stdcall;
  external 'netapi32.dll' Name 'NetWkstaGetInfo';

function GetDomain: string;
var
  PBuf: PByte;
  Res: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  Res := NetWkstaGetInfo(nil, 100, @PBuf);
  if (Res = NERR_Success) then begin
    Result := LPWKSTA_INFO_100(PBuf)^.wki100_langroup; // ACCESS_VIOLATION here
    if Assigned(PBuf) then
      NetApiBufferFree(PBuf);
  end;
end;
```

Screenshots from Win32:
[image: Win32]

and Win64 breakpoints:
[image]

Comment: You're using `Pointer` instead of `PByte`. A 64 bit platform has 64 bit pointers, unsurprisingly. It just works by chance under 32 bit either.

Comment: Unfortunately after changing Pointer to PByte I have the same exception after compiling under x64, under x32 PByte works

Comment: Don't forget to edit your question with the actual code you used.

Comment: `NetWkstaGetInfo` expects the **address** of a pointer as its final argument. I'm not exactly familiar with Delphi, but I'm guessing you need `@PBuf`.

Comment: Changed question with your suggestions, the same issue. Added screenshots. On the Win64 screenshot we can see that ver_major value moved to ver_minor

Comment: @AmigoJack: Both `Pointer` and `PByte` are native-sized integers.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, the `@` is not needed since the parameter is declared as a `var` parameter.

Comment: @AlexEgorov: Are your Win32 and Win64 screenshots from the same computer?

Comment: Your code has one obvious bug: You must write `if Assigned(PBuf) then
    begin
      Result := LPWKSTA_INFO_100(PBuf)^.wki100_langroup;
      NetApiBufferFree(Buf);
    end` because if `PBuf` is `nil`, you cannot access `LPWKSTA_INFO_100(PBuf)^.wki100_langroup`. Otherwise, it works for me both on Win32 and on Win64.

Comment: Probably some other code changed record alignment. Try adding `{$A8}` before WKSTA_INFO_100 record declaration.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar than you for your suggestion about {$A8} before WKSTA_INFO_100 declaration, with this alignment all works fine now. But is it strange. Code is the same, but it is complex code from big project, probably third parts changed alignment for Win64. Can you put you suggestion as answer and I will accept it for closing the question?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand in the block if (Res = NERR_Success) then (...) we should not check that PBuf is assigned, because function return correct value. I think we even can remove if Assigned(PBuf) before freeing the memory block?

Comment: @AlexEgorov: All I know for sure is this: **if** it is possible that `PBuf` is `nil` inside the `if Res = NERR_Success then` body, **then** you must also protect your field access using an `if Assigned(PBuf) then`; **otherwise**, the `if Assigned(PBuf) then` that is currently present in your code is unnecessary. In fact, if `PBuf = nil` is possible, it might be more important to protect the field access than the Win API call, since the field access will AV on a `nil` pointer while the Win API call likely handles a null pointer rather well.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand "*No, the @ is not needed since the parameter is declared as a var parameter*" - except that in the current code shown, the `var` was dropped when `Pointer` was changed to `PByte`. The `var` needs to be re-added.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, this was test, var is restored with PByte, but with Pointer it works too, should I use PByte?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms suggest that some other code changed default record alignment for `WKSTA_INFO_100` record type.

Under 32-bit compiler that wouldn't have an impact because all values in the record are also 32-bit therefore they will be correctly aligned even if other alignment size is specified.

Under 64-bit compiler `DWORD` is 32-bit, while LPWSTR is 64-bit. With default 8 byte alignment that means there will be 4 padding bytes inserted after `wki100_platform_id`. If some other alignment is used following fields will not be at correct positions.

To correct this you need to specify 8 byte alignment `{$A8}` before type declaration.

```
type
{$A8}
  WKSTA_INFO_100 = record
    wki100_platform_id: DWORD;
    wki100_computername: LPWSTR;
    wki100_langroup: LPWSTR;
    wki100_ver_major: DWORD;
    wki100_ver_minor: DWORD;
  end;
```